# VBA, Copying work sheet names to a seperate column of mergedsheets workbook

Tags: vba, merge

I wrote this code to merge all my worksheets into `sheet(1)` and inserted few columns to differentiate the data of different sheets.

Code is as below:

```
Sub Combine()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xTCount As Variant
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next

    Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    xWs.Name = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 16)
    Worksheets("Presanitization").Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")

    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("A1") = "Identifier"
    Range("B1") = "Batch ID"
    Range("C1") = "Phase"

    For i = 4 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(1), 0).Copy _
               Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 4)

    Next

    Worksheets(1).Columns("A:l").ColumnWidth = 16
    Worksheets(1).Columns("A:z").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Worksheets(1).Range("B2") = xWs.Name
    Worksheets(1).Range("A2") = Left(xWs.Name, Len(xWs.Name) - 3)

End Sub
```

Now, I want to copy the worksheet names into `column "C"` of my worksheet and copy it down till the end of the data for that sheet.

How can I repeat this for all the data?

Can anybody help me in modifying my code ?